Why SQL not found in DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT that is executed yesterday only?
I have executed a sql statement yesterday to check the performance of the query but today I am not able to find the sql in dba_hist_sqtext.
Please suggest how to track that SQL?

dba_hist_sqltext only contains the text of SQL that is present in the shared pool at the time of an AWR snapshot and recorded in either dba_hist_sqlstat or dba_hist_active_sess_history. If the query is less than 10 seconds it may not be in ASH on disk and if it drops from the shared pool before the next AWR snapshot won't be in sqlstat either. The purpose of these views is to examine performance problems, not be an audit of every SQL statement ran.
If you need a history of all your SQL, I recommend you use your database client software which hopefully has a logging mechanism available. If so, enable logging all database calls to a log file. I keep my log files for years and they are very valuable for searching up something I ran months ago. Using the database itself for that purpose doesn't work nearly as well.
